# Is there a way to modify a Search Menu to hide the menu before typing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

(See the code below.)

I'd like to hide the menu options before typing into the search.

I'd also ideally like to require a 2 or 3 character match before displaying results.

The hiding has priority.

I have attempted to change numerical values and the display attribute. The initial CSS overrides, as I'm sure is the standard behavior.

```js
   
    function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
    /* Style the search box */
    #mySearch {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 11px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    /* Style the navigation menu */
    #myMenu {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    /* Style the navigation links */
    #myMenu li a {
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myMenu li a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
    
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started.  let me know if you need more help

```js
function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
      
      var sbv = input.value
      
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
      
      if (sbv.length > 2){
         ul.style.display = "block"
      }else{
         ul.style.display = "none"
      }
      
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
/* Style the search box */
    #mySearch {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 11px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      
    }
    
    /* Style the navigation menu */
    #myMenu {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display:none;
    }
    
    /* Style the navigation links */
    #myMenu li a {
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myMenu li a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
    
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
    </ul>
```